# How to slice a reduced gaussian gridded grib with xarray?

Tags: coordinate-system, xarray

I want: 
to get list of coordinates of points within the specified area (ideal would be geopandas from shapefile or something like this)
I don't want to interpolate the grib, just extract points by coordinates x,y
The GRIB is ECMWF reduced gaussian, so it is not a regular grid.

How can I do this from xarray dataarray (opened with cfgrib)?
How can I just get a list of lats and longs?

Here is the grib_var info:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'tp' (values: 1252347)>
dask.array<open_dataset-4b0a50a5721767d0c4be8de49d37aaa8tp, shape= 
(1252347,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1252347,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
   number      int64 ...
   time        datetime64[ns] ...
   step        timedelta64[ns] ...
   surface     int64 ...
   latitude    (values) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1252347,), 
    meta=np.ndarray>
   longitude   (values) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1252347,), 
    meta=np.ndarray>
   valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: values
Attributes:
   GRIB_paramId:                    228
   GRIB_shortName:                  tp
   GRIB_units:                      m
   GRIB_name:                       Total precipitation
   GRIB_cfVarName:                  tp
   GRIB_dataType:                   fc
   GRIB_missingValue:               9999
   GRIB_numberOfPoints:             1252347
   GRIB_totalNumber:                0
   GRIB_typeOfLevel:                surface
   GRIB_NV:                         0
   GRIB_stepUnits:                  1
   GRIB_stepType:                   instant
   GRIB_gridType:                   reduced_gg
   GRIB_gridDefinitionDescription:  Gaussian Latitude/Longitude Grid
   GRIB_N:                          1280
   GRIB_pl:                         (588, 592, 596, 600, 604, 608, 612, 
        616,...
   long_name:                       Total precipitation
   units:                           m
```

Comment: You may think of reshaping first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845442/how-to-reshape-xarray-data-with-new-dimensions